# Dimension Recovery of $S \subset P_n(F)$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces, field-theory

How is the subset of $P_n(F)$ consisting of all polynomials $f$ such that
$f(1) = 0$ a subspace of $P_n(F)$? What is the dimension of this subset?

---

**Added from answer posted by Trancot on 18 Apr 2013:**

This is what I had:

> Let $S=\{f \in P_n(F) : f(1)=0\}$. Clearly, the polynomial $f(x)=0 \in S$ because $f(c)=0$ for any choice of $c\in F$. To demonstrate closure under addition and multiplication consider the fact that $cf(1)+g(1)=c\cdot 0+0=(cf+g)(1)=0$ for $f,g\in S$

Does this suffice to show subspace existence?

Comment: I know that the set $S=\{f \in P_n(F) : f(1)=0\}$ being a subspace of $P_n(F)$ has dimension $\leq n+1$.

Comment: At this immediate point in time, I suspect it is $n$.

Comment: So... you're asking how to find the kernel of a linear transformation? (If the answer is no, then you should figure out why you should be!)

Comment: @Hurkly The argument is $1$ not $x$.

Comment: People seem to like Wikipedia these days... Here is a [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28linear_algebra%29) of interest to those onlookers who are curious.

Comment: I'm aware. Maybe it would help to write the problem in terms of a basis for $P_n(F)$?

Comment: @Hurkyl The basis for $P_n(F)$ is $\{1,x^2,x^3,\dots,x^n\}$. Hmm... Can $S$ have a $1$ in its basis?

Comment: $(x-1)^2=x^2-2x+1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to show this: evaluation at $1$ is a linear transformation from $P_n(F)$ to $F$.  Write $\epsilon: P_n \to F$ for $\epsilon(f(x)) = f(1)$.  If $f(x), g(x) \in P_n(F)$ and $k \in F$, then $\epsilon(f(x) + kg(x)) = \epsilon(f(x)) + k\epsilon(g(x)) = f(1) + kg(1)$.

The subspace of polynomials vanishing at $1$ is the kernel of this linear transformation.  It is plain that $\epsilon$ is surjective, so $\dim(\text{Image}(\epsilon)) = \dim(F) = 1$.  By the rank-nullity theorem, $\dim(\ker(\epsilon)) = \dim(P_n(F)) - 1 = n$.

Comment: I like this, and I blindly see it as true. I don't know that there are any holes.

Comment: BTW, I hope your friends and family are OK. I mean, with what happened recently in Boston and all.